# SpinButton: public property 'value' is undefined and public method 'focus()' is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

I have recently started with reactjs, typescript and Office UI Fabric. But I'm already struggling with one of the components from fabric.
In this example I have a simple Product component with a SpinButton and a DefaultButton.
When the DefaultButton is clicked I want to get the value of the SpinButton and set the focus on it.
In order to get the ISpinButton interface members I'm using a ref of React.RefObject.
My code looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { DefaultButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import { SpinButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/SpinButton';

class Product extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    private spbStockRef: React.RefObject<SpinButton> = React.createRef<SpinButton>();

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <SpinButton
                    ref={this.spbStockRef}
                    defaultValue="0"
                    label={'Stock '}
                    min={0}
                    max={99999}
                    step={1}
                    onFocus={() => console.log('onFocus called')}
                    onBlur={() => console.log('onBlur called')} />
                <DefaultButton onClick={this.onButtonClick} />
            </React.Fragment>)
    }

    private onButtonClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        const node = this.spbStockRef.current!;

        if (node) {
            console.log(node.value);
            node.focus();
        }
    }
}
export default Product;
```

Inside onButtonClick the intellisense of Visual Studio suggests both 'value' and 'focus()' on the node variable so the actual ISpinButton members should be accessable.

But when the button is clicked the console.log(node.value) outputs **undefined** and a TypeError is raised on node.focus():
**TypeError: node.focus is not a function**.
I also want to mention that console.log(node) outputs a proper instantiated object so the ref is working properly.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?
In the examples of the SpinButton component there's also nothing that points out how to make this work.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric?example=#/components/spinbutton

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired on Boy With Silver Wings his answer I have found a workaround. Instead of using a specific type for the RefObject I just declared it as **any** and then I was able to use the componentRef.
So basically I had to override the required type **(component?: ISpinButton | null) => void** of the componentRef to make it work. I don't know if this should be reported as a bug.

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { DefaultButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import { SpinButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/SpinButton';

class Product extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    private spbStockRef: any = React.createRef();

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <SpinButton
                    componentRef={this.spbStockRef}
                    defaultValue="0"
                    label={'Stock '}
                    min={0}
                    max={99999}
                    step={1}
                    onFocus={() => console.log('onFocus called')}
                    onBlur={() => console.log('onBlur called')} />
                <DefaultButton onClick={this.onButtonClick} />
            </React.Fragment>)
    }

    private onButtonClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        const node = this.spbStockRef.current!;

        if (node) {
            console.log(node.value);
            node.focus();
        }
    }
}
export default Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

For `fabric-ui`, to attach a ref to the inner element and not the component, you can use [`componentRef`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/React-Guidelines#consuming-a-components-public-api)

That would make code for `SpinButton`:

```
<SpinButton
   componentRef={this.spbStockRef}
   defaultValue="0"
   label={'Stock '}
   min={0}
   max={99999}
   step={1}
/>
```

```js
const { SpinButton } = window.Fabric;

class App extends React.Component {
  spinBtn = React.createRef();
  componentDidMount() {
    this.spinBtn.current.focus();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SpinButton
        defaultValue="0"
        label={'Basic SpinButton:'}
        min={0}
        max={100}
        step={1}
        componentRef={this.spinBtn}
        iconProps={{ iconName: 'IncreaseIndentLegacy' }}
      />
    );
  }
}

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/9.6.1/css/fabric.min.css">
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/office-ui-fabric-react/dist/office-ui-fabric-react.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion but this doesn't work for me with typescript. If I use componentRef instead of ref I get following type mismatch error: **(TS) Type 'RefObject<{}>' is not assignable to type '(component?: ISpinButton | null | undefined) => void'.
  Type 'RefObject<{}>' provides no match for the signature '(component?: ISpinButton | null | undefined): void'.**

Comment: So it only accepts a method and not a RefObject as I also would expect: From the documentation [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric?example=#/components/spinbutton#Implementation) ISpinButtonProps interface / componentRef (component?: ISpinButton | null) => void

Comment: I'm not sure why typescript does not work, as you can see the code just works. Might be with the typings

Comment: Yes, indeed. I don't know why the componentRef has to be a method instead of a RefObject in case of the SpinButton.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't really see that the focus is set on the SpinButton when I run your code snippet so I'm not sure if it actually works?

Comment: The 0 in SpinButton should be focused on `componentDidMount`, it has a blue border too. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using FireFox 63.0.3. I hadn't tested this in Chrome till now and I have to confirm that it does work.